# Ffmpeg: Arguments for optimizing video stream?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video, performance

I'm using FFmpeg from a Debian machine on my local network. This machine is listening from incoming streams:

```
$ ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.1.3:8080 /path/to/out.avi
```

And from my MacBook, sending the video in AVI format:

```
$ ffmpeg -f <input> -i "1" -f avi udp://192.168.1.3:8080
```

The above commands work, but I'm looking for some FFmpeg optimization tips and tricks for minimizing the CPU load on my MacBook while maintaining the video output quality.

[image]

Any optimization arguments like **bitrate** (I don't really know what this is), **file format alternatives** (something better than avi?), **resolution**, **protocol** (udp alternatives?), anything at all that might keep the CPU usage to an absolute minimum without completely ruining the quality of the video output.

**TL;DR:** How can I minimize the CPU/MEMORY usage on my MacBook without destroying the video output quality?

Comment: Instead of streaming an AVI, try mpegts (MPEG Transport Stream).   So the output should be `-f mpegts udp://XX.XX.XX.XX:YYYY`